# Problemas na integração entre C++ e C#

Tags: c#, c++, unity3d, dll

Olá, estou tendo problemas com a integração entre uma DLL em C++ com o C# da Unity. Achei alguns códigos (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27390856/cant-marshal-array-of-stucts-from-c-to-c-sharp-in-unity)

Esse é meu codigo C++, nele teoricamente eu envio uma estrutura com 2 pontos para a Unity em C#.

```
struct Pontos {
int i;
float f;
};
Pontos **pontos;
DllExport bool SetPoints(Pontos *** a, int *i)
{
pontos = new Pontos*[4];
for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
        pontos[j] = new Pontos; // Actually create each object.
        pontos[j]->i = j;
        pontos[j]->f = (float)j;
    }
    *a = pontos;
    *i = 4;
    return true;
}
```

Aqui o Codigo em C#, onde eu tento receber os pontos que envio e salvar. No Unity onde o script fica adicionado aparece a seguinte mensagem "No MonoBehaviour scripts in the file, or their names do not match the file name", não sei o que isso significa.

```
[DllImport("dll")]
 private static extern bool SetPoints(out IntPtr ptrResultVerts, out int resultVertLength);
public struct Pontos
{
int i;
float f;
};     
void Start()
{ 
IntPtr ptrNativeData = IntPtr.Zero;
int itemsLength = 0;

bool success = SetPoints(out ptrNativeData, out itemsLength);
if (!success)
{
    return;
}

Pontos[] SArray = new Pontos[itemsLength];  // Where the final data will be stored.
IntPtr[] SPointers = new IntPtr[itemsLength];

Debug.Log("Length: " + itemsLength); // Works!
Marshal.Copy(ptrNativeData, SPointers, 0, itemsLength); // Seems not to work.

for (int i = 0; i < itemsLength; i++)
{
    Debug.Log("Pointer: " + SPointers[i]);
    SArray[i] = (Pontos)Marshal.PtrToStructure(SPointers[i], typeof(Pontos));
}
```

Se alguém souber o que está errado por favor me ajude. Valeu.

Comment: Esse seu segundo código, em C#, não deveria ser uma classe herdada de `MonoBehavior`? Vc copiou só um trecho de código, ou o script tá todo assim mesmo? Se estiver todo assim (isto é, sem a definição da classe e da herança), eu acho que o erro é bem óbvio: ele não é um script válido da Unity.

Comment: É só um trecho do código, na declaração eu herdo a MonoBehavior